# Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined - Sometimes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, express, google-maps-api-3

I have a website that allows users to post a form including an address for a google map.

I'm having a odd problem with Google maps API. **Occasionally** I will get the error "Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined" and occasionally I will not. Maybe 1/4 of the time I'll get the error. I know it has to do with finding a location but I am validating locations prior to posting the form so I should not be having this issue? I thought I might be exceeding Google's amount of posts per minute or something but their limits are very high so that cannot be the issue. Any idea why this is happening?

See code below:

FRONT END:

```
function initMap() {
    var lat = <%= listings.lat %>;
    var lng = <%= listings.lng %>;
    var center = {lat: lat, lng: lng };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: center,
        scrollwheel: false
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: map
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Address validation:

```
  $("#checkingAddress").click(doGeocode);


function doGeocode(){

  var addr = document.getElementById("location");
    // Get geocoder instance
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // Geocode the address
    geocoder.geocode({'address': addr.value}, function(results, status){
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {

            // set it to the correct, formatted address if it's valid
            addr.value = results[0].formatted_address;;

        // show an error if it's not
        }else alert("Invalid address");
    });
};
```

POST ROUTE:

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
    var currentimages = allimages;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var acres = req.body.acres;
    var rooms = req.body.rooms;
    var baths = req.body.baths;
    var footage = req.body.footage;
    var directions = req.body.directions;
    var schools = req.body.schools;
    var link = req.body.link;
    var mls = req.body.mls;
    var createdby = req.body.createdby;
    var createdbyemail = req.body.createdbyemail;
    var desc = req.body.description;
    var search = req.body.search;
    var price = req.body.price;
    geocoder.geocode(req.body.location, function (err, data) {
    var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    var location = data.results[0].formatted_address;
    var amenities = req.body.amenities;
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username,
        email: req.user.email
    }
var newListings = {acres: acres, landoption: landoption, rooms: rooms, baths: baths, footage: footage, directions: directions, schools: schools, link: link, mls: mls, name: name, currentimages: currentimages, createdby: createdby, createdbyemail: createdbyemail, description: desc, price: price, search: search, author:author, location: location, lat: lat, lng: lng, amenities: amenities}

    Listings.create(newListings, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log('this2' + err);
        } else {

 res.redirect("/listings");
        }
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Maybe there is no result from the geocode call, so data.results[0] is undefined.  Also, storing the lat/lng/location from the geocode callback in local variables won't make them available to the parent function, nor will they get populated when you think they will.

Comment: @James Thanks for the help. Not sure I understand the thought of no result in the geocode call. I can see the address format to a address that Google verify prior to posting the form. Interesting. How would I chance the lat/lng/location to be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I split up the newListings object into fields that are available when the initial function runs, and those that are only available in the geocode callback.

In the geocode callback I do a quick test to make sure that there are some results, and if there are, then add them to the newListings object.

Also in the geocode callback create the new Listings.  This has to be in the callback because otherwise it will get triggered before the callback ever happens.

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){

    // create a newListings object with the data available to us on post

    var newListings = {
        acres: req.body.acres,
        rooms: req.body.rooms,
        name: req.body.name,
        (etc, with the remaning fields)
    };

    // initiate a call to geocode.  When the geocode is complete, add other fields to our newListings object
    geocoder.geocode(req.body.location, function (err, data) {
        if (data && data.results && data.results.length) { // there are some results
            newListings['lat'] = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            newListings['long'] = data.results[0].geometry.location.long;
            newListings['location'] = data.results[0].formatted_address;
        }

        // only once we have either tried and failed to process the geocode result, or succeeded and populated our newListings object, can we continue
        Listings.create(newListings, function(err, newlyCreated){
            if(err){
                console.log('this2' + err);
            } else {
                res.redirect("/listings");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help I'm working on implementing this. It does seem to be working however now the map does not show on the front end. I added my front end code above. Any thoughts? :)

Comment: Ah! I see the problem: "long" does indeed have to be "lng"

Comment: James what can I say, this works! Thank you so so much! I just successfully posted the form about 40 times without error.